# Tray application : Create UI on main thread from background thread event handler

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I'm playing around with a tray application. The application runs only in the System Tray and has no Windows Form associated with it. The application uses a ManagementEventWatcher and displays an alert window in certain scenarios.

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

    Application.Run(new AppContext());
}
```

...

```
public class AppContext : ApplicationContext
{
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer _components;
    private NotifyIcon _notifyIcon;
    private ContextMenuStrip _contextMenu;
    private ManagementEventWatcher _regWatcher;


    public AppContext()
    {
        //Initialize context menu & tray icon

        _regWatcher = new ManagementEventWatcher(query);
        _regWatcher.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(_regWatcher_EventArrived);
        _regWatcher.Start();
    }

    void _regWatcher_EventArrived(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
    {
        Alert.Show("Alert!", "My Message", someParam);
    }
}
```

...

```
public class Alert
{
    public static void Show(string title, string message, string extraInfo)
    {
        new Alert(title, message, extraInfo).ShowDialog();
    }

    private Alert(string title, string message, string extraInfo)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.Icon = Properties.Resources._default;
        this.Text = title;
        this.label1.Text = message;
        this.linkLabel1.Text = extraInfo;
    }
}
```

Interestingly, it doesn't complain about not accessing the UI in a thread-safe way. I suppose because it only exists on this background thread. But later on when the Form tries to access the clipboard, it doesn't work because it is running on an MTA thread. So far, all the similar questions I have found already have a form to call Invoke on, or have the option of using a BackgroundWorker. What is the best way to create and display the Alert Form on the main thread in this case?

Comment: See Andy Whitfield's blog [here](http://nosuchblogger.com/post/60/applicationcontext-and-the-ui-thread) where he uses a **SynchronizationContext()** to solve a similar type issue.

Comment: @Idle_Mind That is right on the money! I will explore that.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean by that, @HansPassant. I may have made an assumption somewhere in there, but what I do know is when the _regWatcher_EventArrived event handler executes, System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ThreadState is Background and System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ApartmentState is MTA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Idle_Mind's link to [Andy Whitfield's blog post](http://nosuchblogger.com/post/60/applicationcontext-and-the-ui-thread) I've arrived at a solution. I added a private global SynchronizationContext to the AppContext class. In the constructor I initialize it to an instance of a WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext. Then when the registry watcher's event occurs, I can Post the task back to the main thread.

```
public class AppContext : ApplicationContext
{
    private SynchronizationContext _uiThreadContext;
    ...
    public AppContext()
    {
        //Initialize context menu & tray icon

        _uiThreadContext = new WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext();

        _regWatcher = new ManagementEventWatcher(query);
        _regWatcher.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(_regWatcher_EventArrived);
        _regWatcher.Start();

        ...
    }

    private void _regWatcher_EventArrived(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
    {
        ...
        _uiThreadContext.Post(new SendOrPostCallback(MyEventHandler), parameters) 
    }
```

Comment: `SynchronizationContext.Current` returns the UI thread context if you call it on the UI thread (after starting your `Application` class). Quite nice shorthand.